# Packaging .NET 3.5 Framework and Drivers in an Adobe AIR install

Tags: .net, air

I have an air app that uses a native process.  This process is a command line tool that interacts with a USB dongle.

The dongle is third party and has it's own library that I interact with.  The library requires .NET 3.5.  It also has its own drivers that may or may not be automatically downloaded from windows update.

I have a native installer that packages up the air app and the native process.  I'm trying to find a way to detect if the user has .net 3.5 and the USB drivers and to install them if they are not available.

One idea is to package the air install in a .NET package.  Not sure if that would work though, I don't have a lot of experience with desktop apps.

Comment: I do believe it is against the typical Microsoft agreement to distribute the .NET Framework within another installer.  It sounds like you need to use an installer the is able to detect if the .NET Framework is installed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just require the user to install the .NET framework before installing the app.  Most people already have it installed and we haven't ran into any installation issues.